# c# webbrowser show what you want

Tags: c#, .net, browser

i want create small web browser , tiny and fast

but i have problem ,

let me explain :

1 - user enter site : google.com
2 - c# program get google.com
3 - find `<td nowrap="" align="center">` 
4 - in web browser only show that area

i dont know where i must start ,

thanks

Comment: I think he's asking for a control which, given a URL and some kind of XPath, shows you just that portion of the page's content.

Comment: @John yes , sorry if i make you all confuse , im only windows programer not a web

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I'm going to try answer your question, but I am deciphering as well.

1. Create a `WebBrowser` control on your form. (2.0 is fine for what you need) and `.Navigate("http://www.google.com");`
2. Get the source code from the Document. You can do this as follows: `string source = _WebBrowser.Document.Body.OuterHtml;`
3. Use string manipulation to get to the area on the page you need. For instance `.SubString()` functions
4. Save the text into a file, or stream and load it into the `WebBrowser` control, or replace the pages Document HTML with just the HTML you are wanting to show.

Comment: For #3, you might get better and easier results by using a regular expression instead of SubString() and friends.

Answer (score 2):

Okay! Looking at the comment it seems you want to request for a page using c# and show only one part of the page. In your case its that specific `<td>` . Please correct me if I am wrong.

Other than what Kyle has mentioned. Check out [HTML agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack). It might be of interest to you.